# FCM Notification is not received in android version 8+ also onMessageReceived() not getting called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Here is my code**

```
@Override
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


  Intent intent = new Intent(this, SOMEACTIVITY.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);


        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);


        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_white_icon);

        if (image != null) {
            notificationBuilder
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                            .bigPicture(image).setSummaryText(messageBody));/*Notification with Image*/
        } else {
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody));
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel Name",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

 }
```

Can any one help me 
firebase dependency  : implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'

buidgradle main :  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

i have tried [FCM Notifications not getting called in background for Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137842/fcm-notifications-not-getting-called-in-background-for-oreo)

Comment: How are you sending messages?

Comment: it's issue of fcm token just because of updating firebase dependancy.